# Is using string concatenation+eval() to build SQLAlchemy queries okay, or is there a better alternative?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using React-Admin as my front end which calls my API using Flask-Restful.

When I use filters, it sends a key value pair in a dict. Between 0 and 3 key value pairs may be requested from my API depending on how many filters are used at once.

I have successfully used a range of if statements to see if the key is in the dict and if it is add the corresponding part of the filter to the query.

However, I have heard it is unsafe to use eval() as others can inject code into your app. I believe as I am setting the strings, it isn't possible. Is this safe to use or is there a better way to set a query using flask-sqlalchemy?

```py
    def find_all(cls, sort, fltr):
        order = sort[1]
        if order == 'ASC':
            s = sort[0]
        else:
            s = sort[0] + " desc"
        query_name = "cls.query."
        if "T" in fltr:
            query_name += 'filter(cls.title.like("%"+fltr["T"]+"%")).'
        if "c" in fltr:
            if fltr['c']:
                query_name += "filter_by(complete=False)."
        if "a" in fltr:
            query_name += 'filter(cls.assigned_id.like("%"+str(fltr["a"])+"%")).'
        query_name += 'order_by(s).all()'
        return eval(query_name)
```

where `fltr` is the dict.

This is working fine, although is it safe to use in a webapp?

Comment: SQLAlchemy is very intentionally built to support metaprogramming -- you don't need to build your filters up as strings, you can build them up as code.

Comment: that is: `q = cls.query; if "T" in fltr: q = q.filter(cls.title.like(...)); if "c" in fltr: q = q.filter_by(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct questions here.

---

#### Is it safe?

Because the queries can only be composed of segments made from constant substrings you wrote and audited yourself, **yes**. If you ever substituted user-provided data into those queries, that would no longer be true.

---

#### Is it good practice?

**Absolutely not.** There's a performance penalty, a readability penalty, a correctness penalty (insofar as static checking tools can't read the AST for statements hidden behind `eval()`), and if someone else in the future wanted to substitute in user-provided data, the original code makes it easier for them to go the string-substitution route and introduce vulnerabilities later.

Consider instead:

```
    def find_all(cls, sort, fltr):
        order = sort[1]
        if order == 'ASC':
            s = sort[0]
        else:
            s = sort[0] + " desc"
        q = cls.query
        if "T" in fltr:
            q = q.filter(cls.title.like("%"+fltr["T"]+"%"))
        if "c" in fltr and fltr['c']:
            q = q.filter_by(complete=False)
        if "a" in fltr:
            q = q.filter(cls.assigned_id.like("%"+str(fltr["a"])+"%"))
        return q.order_by(s).all()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was so close to the right solution. When you talk about penalties, I understand the readability and correctness. Can you explain why there is a performance penalty? I am learning and want to understand more.

Comment: `eval` requires engaging the parser each time it's called; without it, all parsing is done only once when the module is loaded. Also, if you're using a Python runtime that does JIT compilation (like PyPy or Numba), using `eval` defeats its ability to refine codepaths after observing their actual usage.